# Kali Linux screen recorder

Tags: kali-linux, recording

I want kali linux default screen recorder on my Ubuntu but don't know the name since I do not have the kali linux. The unique property which make me fall in love with it was the icon on the top panel appears once kali linux starts. I tried to find out the default packages of kali linux but everywhere only penetrating tools are listed.

Comment: You mean recordmydesktop? Check here: http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php

Comment: But record my desktop is not pinning itself on top panel (near to wifi, battery icons)

Comment: Well I guess it should be some configuration that you have to do.. I have never used a screen recorder, but as far as you see it in videos regarding Kali, that they use the same program, then it's probably a simple configuration on recordmydesktop program.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://hackerspace.kinja.com/screen-recording-in-linux-1686055808) is someone's list of the top four Linux screen recorders and how to install them.  I hope this list includes what you are looking for.

Comment: It was kazam but I still don't kow how to pin it to panel.

Comment: But I found out similar vokoscreen with 'hide windows' option. I added it in startup program. Hoping it to appear with hidden windows on startup.

Answer (score 0):

***Getting the right Screen Recorder***

Although Kali Linux has a screen recorder built-in, I would suggest getting a similar screen recorder that is very easy to install and customize. The name of it is "Simple Screen Recorder".

***Why should you use it?***

The name says it all. This is a simple screen recorder that can be fully customized to your needs.

***Benefits of SSR:***

- SSR is multi-threaded
- SSR is capable for Live streaming of videos
- SSR supports many different types of codecs like MKV, WebM, MP4 etc
- SSR can record on 32-bit OpenGL application within a 64-bit OS

***How to Install SSR:***

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

Answer (score 0):

The one your talking about is "EasyScreenCast" it is a gnome extension and as @blametheadmin said it uses gtk-recordmydesktop which you can use from terminal or if you would like install jack2 qjackctl  and your good to go

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend `green-recorder`.

Step to install through the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install green-recorder
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossproject/ppa
```

Comment: Welcome *Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.*  [Kali sources.list Repositories](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

Comment: I'm not a Kali user, but why would you add a repository *after* (trying to) install the application?

Comment: You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:fossproject/ppa